# Xcode 7 'SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h' file not found

Tags: xcode7, ios9

I have project which is running fine in xcode 6.4 now i am running it in xocde7 beta version. Its giving error 'SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h' file not found

```
/Applications/Xcode7-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Library
```

I searched under this path and not found any SenTestingKit framework. Where as when i look in to xcode 6.4 for the same path there SenTestingKit is present. Any idea why i am getting this error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SenTest was deprecated and removed. There should be an option to upgrade to XCTest. 
I believe in the Refactor menu item or via one of the yellow alert icons in build errors.